# Kubernetes Docker - Do I need to run docker compose when I update a secret?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-secrets

Quick question, do i need to docker compose up on airflow when i amend a secret in kubectl?

I've changed a password using the command line and kubectl in vscode and just want to know if it is necessary to run docker compose up now that it has been changed or not?

Comment: Unless you are using a specific tool that ties docker compose to k8s, they are not otherwise compatible.

Comment: Yes im using microk8s kubectl, and connecting docker to airflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed your `airflow` system using `helm` charts directly on k8s. Then you don't have to do anything. Secrets are automatically refreshed inside pods by the `kubelet`. And you don't have to manipulate docker directly when you already have k8s installed and are interacting with it using `kubectl`. That's the whole point of having k8s.

If you're using both, you shouldn't, really. Just interact with k8s and forget about docker. You will almost never have to think about docker unless you are debugging some serious problem with k8s system itself.

Answer (score 0):

Nah. Docker compose has nothing to do with it. You probably just need to restart your Pods somehow. I always just do a "Redeploy" through our Rancher interface. I'm sure there is a way to do that with kubectl as well. You just need to get the secret into the Pods, the image itself is unchanged.